# Basic Set Theory Proofs (union, intersection, and subsets)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am currently learning Set Theory proofs and saw these questions in my reference book (which I struggled to answer). If possible, I just want to proceed with my proof and learn how the reasoning for the proof works.

1. Prove $(A \cap B) \cup C = A \cap (B \cup C) \Leftrightarrow C \subseteq A$.
2. Prove if $A \cup B \subseteq C \cup D,\ A \cap B = \emptyset,$ and $C \subseteq A,$ then $B \subseteq D$.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

---

*this is what my proof looks like but I don't really know how to proceed or if I'm doing it correctly.

1. Proof. Assume that $(A \cap B) \cup C = A \cap (B \cup C)$. We want to show that $C \subseteq A$. Now,
   $(A \cap B) \cup C = A \cap (B \cup C)$ 
   $(A \cap B) \cup C \subseteq A \cap (B \cup C)$ 
   $(A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C) \subseteq A \cap (B \cup C)$ 
   $(A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C) \subseteq A $ 
   $A \cup C \subseteq A$ **this is actually just an intuition to remove $B \cup C$ because it exists in both sides* \
   $C \subseteq A$.

*I don't know how to write the other direction of the proof.*

2. Proof. Suppose that $A \cup B \subseteq C \cup D,\ A \cap B = \emptyset,$ and $C \subseteq A$. we will prove that $B \subseteq D$. Take $x \in A \cup B$. This means that $x \in A$ or $x \in B$, where $x$ cannot be both in $A$ and $B$ because $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

**This is where I get confused if I'm doing it correctly.*

---

Comment: Why did you delete your previous post with this same question?  It was closed.  [This one which moderators can see, and users with sufficient reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4263705/set-theory-proofs-involving-union-intersection-and-subsets)

Comment: I just edited it then after publishing, it was already closed.

Comment: Then you improve it yet again; it's already been through the reopen queue. It can go through again, if you edit. DO NOT delete a post, only to repost the same question.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't know that it's unappropriate to delete a post.

Comment: One can delete a non-answered post, but not in order to ask the same question in a separate post.

Comment: In $2$, you want to assume $x \in B$ and reason from there.  If $x \in B$, then $x \notin A$ and also $x \in C \cup D$.  Is $x \in C$ possible?  Why or why not?  From this conclusion, what further conclusion can you draw?

Comment: In you proof of $1$, similar as to what Robert Shore argued above , you should begin by taking an arbitrary $x \in C$ and showing tha $x \in A$. As a start, if $x \in C$ then $x \in (A \cap B) \cup C$. After this you are one step away from reaching the answer!

Comment: @GiordanoRibeiro Thank you! For the converse direction, do I have to take $x \in (A \cap B) \cup C$? And because of the = sign, do I also need to show that they are subsets of each other?

Comment: @RobertShore this really helped! Thank you!

Comment: @rmp Exactly! Since you have the equality, it suffices to show that $(A \cap B) \cup C \subseteq A \cap (B \cup C)$ and $ A \cap (B \cup C) \subseteq (A \cap B) \cup C$. You prove each of the claims separately and, in each one, start by taking an arbitrary $x$ on the set you want to prove the containment.